# Split pandas text columns to multiple chunks

Tags: python, pandas

I have two text columns in a pandas Dataframe. However, I want to split them into multiple chunks and expand the rows.

I could make n chunks of one column and expand the Dataframe like this:

```
n = 200
post_df = df.set_index(['summary'])['text'].str.split().apply(
               lambda x: pd.Series([' '.join(x[i:i+n]) for i in range(0, len(x), n)])
            ).stack().reset_index().drop('level_1', 1)
post_df.columns = ["summary","text"]
post_df = post_df.reindex(columns=["text","summary"])
```

This splits the `text` column in chunks of 200 words and expand the rows with those chunks and ALL  the text from `summary`. However, I now want to split both rows 5 times across both columns. For example, if `text` has 1000 words and `summary` has 200 words. I want to split them into 5 rows with 200 words in `text` and 40 words in `summary`.

How can I achieve this?